# Search Local Context and Database With Single Query

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using EF6 and would like to run a query that has results from both the local context and the database, without duplicates.

Is there a way to tell Entity Framework to do this?

Comment: What is the use case here? Are you trying to handle a case where changes have been made both locally and in the database (from another source)?

Comment: I would like to find all entities that have been added or changed locally with a specific condition AND all of the entities that have that same condition on the database so that i can modify their data further. So yes, exactly what you said.